# What keyComparator can be used in Comparator.comparing(Function keyExtractor, Comparator keyComparator)?

Tags: java, comparator

> Comparator [comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)(Function keyExtractor, Comparator keyComparator)

can be used like this with String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

```
Comparator<Person> cmp = Comparator.comparing(
             Person::getLastName,
             String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

What else can be used in place of keyComparator (besides String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)? I can't think of another example.

Comment: simply too broad unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what other `Comparator<String>` there are in the `String` class, the answer is that there is none.

The [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class as of Java 8 has only one `Comparator<String>`.

However, this does not mean that you can't use other things. Every `Comparator<String>` will work there. If you don't want case insensitive ordering, you can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, `Comparator.reverseOrder()`, or anything you want. You can write a lambda like this to pass it in there as well (though I find the static methods of `Comparator` more readable):

```
(x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.length(), y.length())
```